# prove $g(X)=\{f(x) : x\in X\}$ surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f : X\to Y$ and $g(x):P(X)\to P(Y)$ be functions.

prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if $g(X)=\{f(x) : x\in X\}$ is surjective.

What I tried: $f$ is surjective so for every $y\in Y$ there is $x_0\in X$ so $f(x_0)=y$. If we construct $X$ to be a set of all the $x_0$ then it solves the problem.

P.S.: someone knows if there is a name for the function $g$?

Comment: I suppose that you meant $P(X)$ instead of $P(x)$. Besides whet does “$f$ is surjective if and $g(X)=\{f(x):x\in X\}$ is surjective” *mean*? And, since $f$ and $g$ are not related, how do you expect to prove that there is a connection between $f$ and $g$?

Comment: People have conjectures about what you meant. Just  to be clear, what you _said_ makes no sense at all. $\{f(x)  : x\in X\}$ is not a function, so it makes no sense to talk about  whether it is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that for a subset $A \subseteq X$ you define $g(A) = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$.

If $f$ is surjective, then we want to show that for any $B \subseteq Y$ there exists $A \subseteq X$ such that $g(A) = B$. By definition of $f$ being surjective, for each $y \in B$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $g(x)=y$, so if we do this for each $y \in B$ and collect the corresponding $x$ in a set $A$, we get $g(A)=B$ as desired.

Conversely if $g$ is surjective, then for each $y \in Y$ there exists some subset $A \subseteq X$ such that $g(A) = \{y\}$, which implies $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you made a typo and your function $g$ is in fact defined as $g : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ with $g(A) = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$ for $A \subseteq X$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set.

For a function $f : X \to Y$ and a set $A \subseteq X$, the set $\{f(x) : x \in A\}$ is commonly denoted $f(A)$, and called the *image* of the set $A$.

So, you can see that $g(A) = f(A)$ for all $A \subseteq X$, or more succintly $g = f(\cdot)$, and you can call it $g$ the functional image.

Now, to prove that $f$ is surjective if and only if $g$ is surjective, it is useful to prove the following lemma:

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a surjection and $B \subseteq Y$. Then we have:
>
> $$f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$$
> where for $A \subseteq Y$ we define the *preimage* of $A$ as $f^{-1}(A) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in A\}$.

Indeed, let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. By definition of image, there exists $x \in f^{-1}(B)$ such that $f(x) = y$. But then $y = f(x) \in B$ by definition of preimage since $x \in f^{-1}(B)$.

Conversely, take $y \in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. In particular, $x \in f^{-1}(B)$ so y = $f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(B))$.

Now onto the proof:

Assume that $f$ is surjective. Let $B \subseteq Y$ and consider $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq X$.

Using the lemma  we have:

$$g(f^{-1}(B)) = f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$$

So $g$ is surjective.

Conversely, assume $g$ is surjective. Take $y \in Y$ and consider $\{y\} \subseteq Y$. Since $g$ is surjective, there exists $A \subseteq X$ such that $g(A) = \{y\}$. In particular, $A \ne\emptyset$ because $g(\emptyset) = \emptyset \ne \{y\}$. So, for any $x \in A$ we have $f(x) \in f(A) = g(A) = \{y\}$ so $f(x) = y$. We conclude that $f$ is surjective.